# New to NoSQL and a little confused with creating collections

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

Im a student just starting out on NoSQL and its just not clicking with me. im a little confused on a few points.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
1.Can documents belong to multiple collections?

2.Have I the correct syntax here for creating the Collection?
The [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8rrE.png) is the collection er and a is just a snippet of the full er.

```
db.Animal.insert ( {
 “animal_ID” : “XXXXXXX “,      
 “common_name” :  “Red Squirrel”,
 “IUCN” : “Least Concern (declining)”,
 “photo” :  “qs451xkx6qf4j”,
   “extinct” : {    
     “when” : “null “,
     “reason” : “null”
},
        “invasive” : {
            “threat_level” : “null”,
            “threat” : “null”,
            “how_to_help” : “null”
},
         “native” : {
            “endangerment” : “population declining“,
            “how_to_help” : “providing a little                     extra food, planting some red squirrel-friendly  shrubs and reporting any red or grey squirrel activity”
},
“Fact_sheet” : “{
   “fact_id” : “ “,
   “animal_id” : “ XXXXXXX “,
   “order” : “ Rodentia “,
   “family” : “Sciuridae “ ,
   “species” : “Sciurus vulgaris “ ,
   “size” : “body length 19 to 23 cm, tail length 15   to 20 cm “ ,
   “weight” : “250 to 340 g “ ,
   “lifespan” : “3 years , 7 to 10 in captivity “ ,
   “extra” : “In Norse mythology, Ratatoskr is a red squirrel who runs up and down with messages in the world tree, Yggdrasil, and spreads gossip “ ,
    “habitat” : { [
       “name” : “woodland “, 
       “description” : “a low-density forest   forming open habitats with plenty of sunlight and limited shade “
]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can documents belong to multiple collections?

In MongoDB, no. In other databases, I don't know.

> 2.Have I the correct syntax here for creating the Collection?

To create a collection you would use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/. This call also permits you to pass various collection options.

You are *inserting a document*. In MongoDB when a document is inserted, if the destination collection doesn't exist, it is created automatically by the server.